# How to add multi selection in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

Context: I have two tables.

Table1: Columns(id,location_name)
Table2: columns(id, data1, data2, data3)

Requirement:

I want to give multi selection option on the Grafana dashboard using table 1, where only location names would be listed.

When you select one ore more location, then the corresponding IDs are selected which can be interpolated on the panels to get the data for those IDs.

Things I have done:

Created two variables.

Variable 1: location_name

```
SELECT location_name FROM Table1
```

The preview lists all the names.
Selected the "Multi-value" option.

Variable 2: location_id
The preview returns all the corresponding values of the selected location names.

```
SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE location_name IN ($location_name)
```

Panel Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Table2 WHERE id IN ( $location_id )
```

The above only returns 1 value.

Where as the same query directly on the MySQL DB, returns two values when I populate the ( $location_id ) with ids. Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Table2 WHERE id IN ( '403066','242034' )
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong! Can someone help?

Note: Everything is a string.

Comment: It looks like you don't actually need second variable, and simply want location to de shown as string for user to select, but proceed with id once user selected something. If this is the case, look a the point 4 in [this manual](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#add-a-query-variable). Simple add aliases to your columns.

Comment: Hi @markalex,
I have removed the second variable and kept only one. But still getting error on the Panel.

Below is what I did:

Variable Name: division_id

Variable Query: SELECT division_name AS __text, division_id AS __value
FROM part_db.part_ids_table Used double underscores)

Multiple Selection: Enabled


Panel Query: SELECT COUNT(name) FROM part_db.part_status WHERE division_id = '$division_id'


Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '242034','403066''' at line 1

Comment: Well, you cannot use `division_id = '$division_id'` if you have multiselect, or your query will end up like this: `division_id = ''242034','403066''` which is obviously incorrect sql. Use `division in ($division_id)` instead.

Comment: @markalex, It works now. I need to look in a set of IDs instead of just One.